# :!!echo command not working from sqlcmd

Tags: sql-server-2016, sqlcmd

I have a sql script file which is executed from a batch file and is supposed to execute some sql scripts and write errors and output to files. Here is an example of how the script file looks like:

```
:error ".\DataAndTableScripts\9.0.0\_RunOrderedScripts.err"
:out ".\DataAndTableScripts\9.0.0\_RunOrderedScripts.out"
:on error ignore
go
set nocount on;
print 'Running .\DataAndTableScripts\9.0.0\OrderedFileList.txt'
print 'Start time: ' + convert( varchar, getdate(), 121 );
GO
:!!echo   Table_auth.IdentityApplication.sql
:error ".\DataAndTableScripts\9.0.0\Table_auth.IdentityApplication.err"
:out ".\DataAndTableScripts\9.0.0\Table_auth.IdentityApplication.out"
:r ".\DataAndTableScripts\9.0.0\Table_auth.IdentityApplication.sql"
go
```

The :!!echo  Table_auth.IdentityApplication.sql piece is suppose to print this text in the command prompt window. I initially had this code on SQL 2014, but when I upgraded to SQL 2016 and to command line utilities 13 this echo piece stopped working. It seems like, even when I have :on error ignore, when it gets to :!!echo, if fails and the rest of the script is not executed.

Anyone has an idea of what the issue may be?

Comment: `:!!` does not work, it's a bug. see: [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54634214/sqlcmd-dir-producing-no-output/54634431?noredirect=1#comment96064739_54634431)   and/or   [microsoft](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/17e489ff-9982-4905-9711-2751d56f7a2d/sqlcmd-dir-command-fails-to-execute?forum=sqltools)

Comment: Luuk that was very helpful. Do you know if the issue is solve in a newer version of the command line utilities? Or is there a way to fix it?

Comment: alternative to `!!echo` is [PRINT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/print-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 2):

SQLCMD

Next versions do NOT work:

- Version 14.0.2027.2 NT (from: COMMAND LINE UTILITIES FOR MICROSOFT SQL SERVER 2017)
- Version 15.0.1300.359 NT (from: SQL Server 2019 (15.x))

This version works:

- Version 11.0.2100.60 NT x64 (from: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Command Line Utilities)

(on my computer found in 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE')

This was tested by creating a file `sqlcmd.txt` which contains 1 line (`:!! dir`), and checking if this command was executed when performing `sqlcmd -i sqlcmd.txt`.

I think the version 11 that works can be downloaded [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=52680), but do NOT ask why this is named 'Command Line Utilities 13 for SQL Server'), and from a logfile i created during install is installen ina folder named `110`....

Answer (score 0):

I just tested that :!!echo works on this version.

Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-GDR) (KB4293802) - 13.0.5081.1 (X64)
        Jul 20 2018 22:12:40
        Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
        Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: it works fine if you run it from SSMS with sqlcmd mode, but if you execute it from a bat file with sqlcmd it doesn't work